# deadlock and\or return before thread is dead

Tags: c++, pthreads

I'm stuck for about 2 days in the same situation and i'd really appreciate any help.
The main thread is calling the `initDevice()` function, which is opening the file and creating a new thread, which he will be the "writing" thread, with the `writeToDeviceHandler()` function.
The `write2device()` is called from main() and should insert new tasks to write (in the future) to a `map<int,Task*>`. The problem is, that sometimes the application is stuck at some kind of an inifinite loop or a deadlock and sometimes it writes <(# of tasks) to write.
Can anyone see if there's anything wrong in the code?
THANKS!

```
int write2device(char *buffer, int length)
{
    if(is_running)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&tasks_mutex);//LOCK
        int curr_id = getNextAvailableId();
        Task* new_task = new Task(buffer,length, curr_id);
        tasks[curr_id] = new_task;
        pthread_cond_signal(&tasks_cv);
        given_ids.insert(curr_id);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&tasks_mutex);//UNLOCK
        return curr_id;
    }
    return FAIL;
}

int initdevice(char *filename)
{
    is_running = true;
    pthread_cond_signal(&tasks_cv);
    output_file.open(filename);
    if(!output_file.is_open())
    {
        cerr << "Error opening file" << endl;
        is_running = false;
        return SYSTEM_ERROR;
    }
    int res = pthread_create(&writing_thread, NULL, writeToDeviceHandler, NULL);//Create the writing to file thread.
    if(res != 0)
    {
        cerr <<  "Error creating the writing thread" <<endl;
        exit(FAIL);
    }

    return SUCCESS;
}

void *writeToDeviceHandler(void *arg)
{
    Task* curr_task;
    while(is_running)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&tasks_mutex);
        cout << "IN LOOP - size of db: " << tasks.size() << endl;
        if(tasks.empty())
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(&tasks_cv, &tasks_mutex);
        }
        if(tasks.empty()) cout << "Empty, still finding thread" <<endl;
        curr_task = tasks.begin()->second;
        if(curr_task == NULL)
        {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&tasks_mutex);
            continue;
        }
        //copy from tasks to file
        output_file.write(curr_task->getBuff(), curr_task->getLength());

        ids.remove(curr_task->getId());
        tasks.erase(curr_task->getId());
        delete curr_task;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&tasks_mutex);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Use debugger to attach to the stuck process to find out where it gets stuck and why.

Comment: I'm a little worried by  cout<<ing stuff to the standard output while keeping another lock.  cout streaming is probably thread-safe, but probably not very good at it.  I doubt that cout queues up your output and returns 'immediately', it's more likely that a straightforward mutex/futex/spinlock is used to enforce the thread-safety.  This means that, with multiple threads acquiring/releasing another lock and also sometimes streaming text, it is possible that they acquire the locks in a different order.  That would be bad :(

Comment: I would *really* advise that you update your coding style to include RAII. Even if not directly related to your issue, all those manual `delete` and `unlock` will one day bite you in the back. It also seems to me that rather than a `map` of the next tasks to write, what you really want is a **queue**.

Comment: @MatthieuM. - and that's another thing. Also, is it necessary to perform the 'output_file.write' inside the queue lock?  I don't see the point of the queue if lengthy operations are going to be performed while the queue is locked.  It's just asking for contention, apart from anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not correct in that it does not have a loop around the `pthread_cond_wait` call. The `pthread_cond_wait` call can return on spurious wakeup. You **have to** check for your wakeup condition after it returns. In your case it looks like it should be something like this:

```
while (task.empty ())
  pthread_cond_wait(&tasks_cv, &tasks_mutex);
```

Your code also lacks error checking. Do check all return values of all functions for errors.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding to the coding style and other DAST for this mission, it's a rough draft of the code and the DAST is crucial for other parts of the task. THANKS AGAIN!

Answer (score 0):

Your `writeToDeviceHandler` code does all its work while holding the mutex, defeating the point of having the thread at all. If another thread wants to give this thread work to do, it will have to acquire the `tasks_mutex`. To do that, it will have to finish until this thread finishes writing and releases the mutex. So why bother with this thread at all?

When you have a mutex that protects work that needs to be done, the whole point is to actually *do* the work with the mutex released. That way, other threads don't have to wait while you finish the work.